# Disable javadoc check for Bintray upload

Tags: android, javadoc, bintray

I am trying to upload a new version of my library to Bintray, however I am getting errors.

One of the changes I made was to add a custom attribute to my Javadoc. For example:

```
/**
 * The method does something.
 *
 * @param myParameter This is my parameter
 * @see #anotherMethod(int)
 * @attr ref R.styleable#MyLibrary_anAttribute
 */
```

The custom attribute tag I added was `@attr ref` which would show related XML attributes when generating Javadoc HTML (like in Android Developer documentation). I added this as a custom tag in my IDE (Android Studio), but it causes an error when uploading to Bintray. Also, I am **using the novoda bintray plugin** - here is part of my `build.gradle`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'

...

publish {
    ...
}
```

So when I run the following command in terminal:

```
gradlew bintrayUpload -PbintrayUser=me -PbintrayKey=key -PdryRun=false
```

I get the following error:

```
:mylibrary:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE      
:mylibrary:mavenAndroidJavadocs
C:\Users\...\ALibraryFile.java:216: error: unknown tag: attr
 * @attr ref R.styleable#MyLibrary_anAttribute

...

13 errors                                             
:mylibrary:mavenAndroidJavadocs FAILED          

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mylibrary:mavenAndroidJavadocs'.
> Javadoc generation failed. Generated Javadoc options file (useful for troubleshooting): 'C:\Users\...\build\tmp\mavenAndroidJavadocs\javadoc.options'

* Try:        
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED  

Total time: 12.711 secs
```

**Is there any way round this** (e.g. disabling this javadoc check?)**?**

Comment: It seems like disabling JavaDoc generation is just masking the problem. I was able to find the error using `./gradlew javadoc`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45748516/3681880).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue by adding the following into my project's `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
        options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
        options.addStringOption('encoding', 'UTF-8')
    }
}
```

I found my answer [from this comment on a GitHub issue](https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release/issues/71#issuecomment-164324255) - you can also view the [GitHub commit that resolved the issue](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/UsefulViews/commit/e73495caae344ddf08f3be88bc7a620f5dfdf1be).

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this is the best way but it works for me. Add

```
    tasks.withType(Javadoc).all {
    enabled = false
    }
```

to your **build.gradle**.

Answer (score 2):

The Javadoc artifacts is one of the artifacts created by the default Maven publication, which is created by the plugin.
The plugin [documentation](https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release/wiki/Defining-a-custom-Publication) explain how to create a custom publication. You can use this option in order to create a custom publication which will not include a javadoc artifact or change the way the Javadoc is generated.