# prevent Javadoc from failing gradle build

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I’m trying to upload my Library project to jCenter.
when I run `gradlew install` I’m getting the error:

> Execution failed for task ':myLibraryProject:javadoc'

I added the code below to my library project:

```
task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    failOnError false // add this line
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.getSrcDirs()
}
```

but still I get

> "Javadoc generation failed. Generated Javadoc options file..."

I've also tried the accepted answer from here: [Generate JavaDocs with Android Gradle plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033878/generate-javadocs-with-android-gradle-plugin)

Can I disable the generation of Javadocs, or maybe try to continue with the build although the failure?

Comment: I found the solution to disable JavaDocs task here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874175/disable-all-javadoc-in-gradle/34874587#34874587

Comment: That solution disables the Javadoc task from running which is different to preventing the build from failing because of bad Javadoc in your code.

Comment: It is helpful to check the files you have, mine was an erroneous import (Android Databinding Library). Fixed by adding the correct config (dataBinding { enabled = true }) in the android{...} on build.gradle (lib). Unfortunately, the problem still persists :(.

Answer (score 5):

I don't recommend disabling JavaDoc generation. Instead, try just running

```
./gradlew javadoc
```

This should give you detailed log output about the warnings and errors that are occurring. Fixing these errors should prevent JavaDoc from causing the failure.

Comment: Tried this and JAVADOC getting generated successfully, but still getting the same error mentioned above.

Comment: @DeepPatel, for me I had to fix the specific errors that were listed in the detailed log output.

Answer (score 4):

> **Add these lines to your module `build.gradle`**

```
tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
      failOnError false
      options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
      options.addStringOption('encoding', 'UTF-8')
      options.addStringOption('charSet', 'UTF-8')
}
```

> **Or you can add these:**

```
android.libraryVariants.findAll { variant -> variant.name == 'Release' } each { variant ->
    task("generate${variant.name}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
        description "Generates Javadoc for $variant.name."
        source = variant.javaCompile.source
        ext.androidJar = "${android.plugin.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
        classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) + files(ext.androidJar)
    }

    task("bundle${variant.name}Javadoc", type: Zip) {
        description "Bundles Javadoc into zip for $variant.name."
        classifier = "javadoc"
        from tasks["generate${variant.name}Javadoc"]
    }
```

Comment: Works with the field `failOnError`

Answer (score 2):

In our case, the problem was that we had to remove .gitignore files. They were listed in the file *javadoc.options*. After that, the task finished successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Run your app without --deviceID. Just run **npx react-native run-android** . It works for me.