# Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I didn't change anything.
**Please somebody help me to solve this:**

> ERROR: Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.setBootClasspath(Ljava/lang/String;)V'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>   Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>   Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
>
> The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>   Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
>
> Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Answer (score 0):

app(build.gradle)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'

        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        google()
    }

    // source :
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34828426/disable-javadoc-check-for-bintray-upload
    tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
        options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
        options.addStringOption('encoding', 'UTF-8')
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```